# map tag not working in HTML

Tags: html, css

For a website I am making, the mapping code won't work, the links remain unclickable. I'm not sure if this is an issue with the CSS/HTML combination or not, but my code is as follows for the HTML part:

```
<div class="subscribe">
    <h2>Follow Us : </h2>
    <div class="contact-form">
        <img src="images/social.png" usemap="#follow">
        <map name="follow">
            <area shape="rect" coords="648,336,1000,600" href="www.instagram.com/quadrotian" target="_blank" alt="Instagram">
            <area shape="circle" coords="1337,336,275" href="www.facebook.com/Quadrotian" alt="Facebook">
            <area shape="circle" coords="2045,336,275" href="#" target="_blank" alt="Pinterest">
            <area shape="circle" coords="2783,336,275" href="#" alt="Twitter">
            <area shape="circle" coords="3491,336,275" href="#" alt="Google Plus">
            <area shape="circle" coords="4206,336,275" href="#" alt="LinkedIn">
        </map>
    </div>
</div>
```

I have used map before in the similar manner but it isn't working this time.

Comment: can you prepare jsbin?

Comment: maybe it has to do with image size and coordonates ? looks hudge, doesn't it ?

Comment: @osmanraifgunes here : https://jsbin.com/cecoto/edit?html,css,output

the font is in white colour, as background had an image

Comment: @GCyrillus should i resize the image to a smaller size?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your map coordinates, shapes and their sizes are way too big. I decreased their sizes by a factor of 10 and look at how big they still are. This is one of your circles:

[image]